# Remove map move event by user

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, bing-maps

How I can handle map move event by user? (Down left mouse button and mouse move)

My goal is remove all users event, which can modification map view.

I using Bing Silverlight Map Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that with this code

```
private void Map_MousePan(object sender, MapMouseDragEventArgs e)
{
        e.Handled = true;
}
```